# Where is the "correct" location to store my Sock Puppet (hat)?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, sock-puppets, fun

I recently obtained Socky and I have no idea what to do with him!

He is is so rambunctious and volatile...

He complains that he wants to be placed **on** my head... but that is just wrong, so wrong, but whenever I go to a mirror to see how Socky looks [I forget what I was doing](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Silent).

So I am asking you: Where should Socky be placed?

[image]

Comment: it's not wrong!

Comment: It is just **too tight** @thekbb

Answer (score 11):

On your hand, where any good sock puppet belongs.

Comment: *[resists temptation to post extremely off-color comment]*

Comment: yes..good i store mine in my set hat

Comment: Here is an example: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10731/hildred

Answer (score 5):

I store mine in my set of winter bash hats. But I think that it has been getting out.

Every once in a while I see a post that seems like it was mine, but ... it was the *sock puppet*! dun dun dun

Keep your socket puppet hidden, no one needs to know about your evil twin or what they are up to. mwuahaha!

Answer (score 4):

How about peeking over your shoulder?

Comment: To be serious for a second this will only work if the puppet is facing backwards or could go behind the avatar. As the situation stands, the orientation of the puppet precludes it peeking over the shoulder when viewed from a screen. Obviously, what the secret computer unicorn gremlins see is a completely different matter.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards *To be serious for a second ... secret computer unicorn gremlins* You just couldn't hold it for that long, could you?

Comment: Half a second then @JDB...

Comment: @JDB Secret computer unicorn gremlins are serious business.

Comment: @Servy Oh dear... I hope I haven't offended them. I really didn't mean anything by it. Wait.. what's that on my screen? Oh sh....  TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a handful...  *BA DUM TSS!*

But seriously, if he gets out of hand, sock him one. They really can't reason.

If all else fails, bring the cat. Cats are always awesome.

I'll see myself out.