# How to search all meta sites

Tags: support, search, stack-exchange, per-site-meta, global-search

I saw a question on a meta site earlier today, but didn't have an answer then. I thought about it for a while, and now have an answer. The problem is I can't remember which meta it was on. Is there a way to search multiple meta sites at the same time, or does anyone know where I can find the question about how to wear a sock puppet hat? (Winter Bash 2013.)

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212414/where-is-the-correct-location-to-store-my-sock-puppet-hat) It's on hold though. You can no longer answer it.

Comment: thanks @JoshC, that is the question I was searching for, and I thought it was probably here, But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try searching on [The Main SE Site](https://stackexchange.com/). The search will return results from the entire network, its not limited to meta sites so you'll have to sift through the results a bit.

For Example: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+wear+a+sock+puppet+hat%3F

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind the results being up to date only until the previous Sunday morning, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) may be of help. With a bit of SQL magic, it can search all per site Metas (and Meta Stack Exchange) for posts with a certain keyword, as [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1482842/networkwide-search-on-meta-sites?query=sock) shows. It even includes sites like Meta Stack Overflow which the Google-inspired answers won't cover.

Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1482842) it if you want additional filtering (on score, creation date, tags, etc.) – obviously that will require some SQL knowledge. If you want assistance with that, check out the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) or visit the [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

<s>There is no way to search all meta sites from within SE (or if there is, then its very well hidden).</s> There is a way to [search all sites within the network including all meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213231/200868).

This is a workaround using Google's wildcard matching. Search using `site:meta.*.stackexchange.com <query>`

For example, `site:meta.*.stackexchange.com sock puppet` gives [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site%3Ameta.*.stackexchange.com+sock+puppet&oq=site%3Ameta.*.stackexchange.com+sock+puppet&gs_l=serp.3...4569.7707.0.7909.8.8.0.0.0.0.171.864.3j5.8.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..8.0.0.8MizELS5l7A).

Comment: This is worth knowing, even if it won't find this question.

Comment: I did _not_ know you could use wildcards in the `site:` modifier. Bravo, sir, bravo.

Answer (score 3):

The "correct"<sup>1</sup> way to do this search from an outside search engine has changed ever since [2017's migration to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/1017231). For [certificate reasons](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), that ended up requiring a move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`. Thus, a search like [`blah blah blah site:meta.stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=blah+blah+blah+site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com) will get hits from all child metas with non-custom domain names (so not e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), as well as main meta.

<sup>1</sup> My opinion on what seems most semantically right.

Answer (score 2):

In https://stackexchange.com, as all per-site meta should include at least one of the mandatory tags, you might helpful to start with something like the following:

[[discussion] or [feature-request] or [bug] or [support]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D%20or%20%5Bfeature-request%5D%20or%20%5Bbug%5D%20or%20%5Bsupport%5D)

Then you could remove the tags that you don't need and add other tags, search operators and keywords to refine the results.

Related

- [Cross Stack Exchange Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59900/289691)
- [New global search doesn't like tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308076/289691)