# New global search doesn't like tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stackexchange.com, global-search

When you visit the global search page:

> [https://stackexchange.com/search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=)

and want to search for a tag like we used to do on the site search like so:

> `[haskell] pattern`

you're directed to the error page with the Panda.

If tag search is supposed to work, can this be fixed? If tag search is not supposed to work there can you at a minimum not throw an error?

Comment: In Soviet Russia, tags don't like the new global search ...

Comment: Huh, didn't expect they'll ever implement cross site search! Most likely it's not done yet and got released too soon by mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if I correctly recite what was mentioned in the Tavern by Shog and Oded this feature existed for 5+ years, was implemented back then by Nick but was only available for internal use, maybe due to these kind edge/special cases that break things. The changed ad policy of the Google enterprise search pushed this change pubic, again if I correctly interpret Shog9's words.

Comment: huh, never saw such thing mentioned. Well, most likely it's a mistake, and they will fix all those bugs by taking it off again, for 6-8 years until they can make it work properly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the search query parsing code. The code was trying to read tag synonyms from a DB table that doesn't exist in the stackexchange.com database. The fix is already deployed. I've only noticed this thanks to exceptions in our log :)

Tag synonyms are not (yet) supported in the global search, as they are a per-site concept, and are handled outside of our elasticsearch index (we'd have to resolve them on *every* Q&A site, before generating the query, and potentially issue multiple different search queries, instead of a single one, like we do now).

Comment: Tags on main search still broken. https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence, will this ever be solved?

Comment: @m0sa This seems too related to file a separate bug (but I don't mind), given the example in the question if you click on the tags returned by the search you get the panda. Another example is searching for the tag Jade, after scrolling past many foreign language sites I arrive at CodeReview.SE; clicking on the [Jade] tag is a panda, but clicking on the question to visit the site ***then*** clicking on the tag works correctly and takes you here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jade --- Fix: each tag should be for the site itself and not for https://stackexchange.com/ . Thx